# How do you dynamically check a dynamically created checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, frontend

Been trying to find reference to exactly what I'm trying to do but not finding anything.

I have part of a form that is added with JS.

Once it has been added, I need to find a checkbox with a specific value and check it.

This works fine on anything that was there when the page loaded, but with dynamically-created elements I can't even manipulate them using JS in the console.

Here's the checkbox HTML:

```
<div class="check-container full optional-extra">
    <input id="Accomodation-Delegates[1]" type="checkbox" name="Delegates[1].SelectedOptionalExtras" value="43b595df-accc-e811-a2dd-00155d0fd300" data-price="25.00">
    <label for="Accomodation-Delegates[1]" class="check-label">Accomodation - £25.00</label>
</div>
```

Here's the section in the jQuery:

```
$('[value="43b595df-accc-e811-a2dd-00155d0fd300"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Please remember that this element doesn't exist on the page when it loads. I know how to dynamically check a checkbox normally.

Comment: It doesn't matter how an element was added to the dom.  The only thing a selector is concerned with is that the element exists at the point that it runs.  So, so long as it has been created before the selector runs, it will find it.

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem and you might need to use [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: My guess is you are calling the jquery before the additional checkboxes have been added to the dom

Comment: @Taplar this is what I was expecting, but If I reference the element in the console it won't even pick it up at that point.

Comment: Look into the `ready` method for your selector. In the callback, add your event listener.
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a set an function (setTimeout on DOMContentLoaded maybe) to trigger after some time after the DOM is initially loaded. This will be a jQuery selector that will look for your element on the page. After you select it, you can do whatever you need to do with it (checking the checkbox, changing background, etc.)

The point is though that you need the element rendered on the DOM at the point that your selector tries to select it (otherwise it will return empty)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [*event-delegation*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to bind events to dynamically created elements.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});

// This is just to demonstrate the dynamic creating process.
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#parent').append($('<div class="check-container full optional-extra"><input id="Accomodation-Delegates[1]" type="checkbox" name="Delegates[1].SelectedOptionalExtras" value="43b595df-accc-e811-a2dd-00155d0fd300" data-price="25.00"><label for="Accomodation-Delegates[1]" class="check-label">Accomodation - £25.00</label></div>'));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ele, but your code example has the same problem as mine. I'm not using a click event, I'm trying to add the checked property (without user interaction) with jQuery .prop('checked', true). This works with any non-dynamically-created element on the page, but the checkboxes that are added with js won't play ball and can't even be manipulated from the console using the ID.